# Java Swing Alignment problem with BoxLayout

Tags: java, swing, alignment, layout-manager, boxlayout

I have three components inside a top to down boxLayout (JLabel, JTextField, JButton). The problem is that when i set the X alignment for the label it looks as if i would've changed the X alignment of the button and vice versa, only when both have the same alignment it works fine.

When the screen gets wider both components take a weird alignment.
[image]

when both components have the same alignment everything works fine.
[image]

here is my code:

```
public void create(){
    JPanel panel =  new JPanel();
    BoxLayout boxLayout = new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);
    panel.setLayout(boxLayout);
    panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10,10,10,10));
    
    JLabel etiqueta =  new JLabel("Numero de consultorio: ");
    etiqueta.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
    etiqueta.setOpaque(true);
    etiqueta.setAlignmentX(Component.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
    panel.add(etiqueta);
    
    JTextField consultorio = new JTextField();
    panel.add(consultorio);
    
    JButton registrar =  new JButton("Registrar");
    registrar.setAlignmentX(Component.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
    panel.add(registrar);
    
    this.getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
}
```

Comment: Not willing to look too closely into this until there is ASCII / art a drawing of the intended GUI **and** a [mre] of your best attempt (not bothering with code snippets). Having said that, I'd likely approach this by putting the component with different alignment into a `JPanel` with `FlowLayout` and adding the panel to the outer box layout with the same layout constraints as the others. The alignment of the component in the flow layout can likewise be sorted using (flow layout) constraints.

Comment: *only when both have the same alignment it works fine.* - correct. That is the way it should work. Read the tutorial on [Fixing Alignment Problems](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html#alignment)

Answer (score 2):

Here is the proposed by Andrew Thompson solution:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class TestFrame {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new TestFrame()::create);
    }

    private void create() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        BoxLayout boxLayout = new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);
        panel.setLayout(boxLayout);
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));

        JLabel etiqueta = new JLabel("Numero de consultorio: ");
        etiqueta.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        etiqueta.setOpaque(true);
        JPanel layout = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEADING, 0, 0));
        layout.add(etiqueta);
        panel.add(layout);

        JTextField consultorio = new JTextField();
        panel.add(consultorio);

        JButton registrar = new JButton("Registrar");
        layout = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.TRAILING, 0, 0));
        layout.add(registrar);
        panel.add(layout);

        JFrame frm = new JFrame("Test");
        frm.getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frm.pack();
        frm.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frm.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frm.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```